# Does an Indian passport holder with a Netherlands Resident Card need a UK transit visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, london, lhr, dutch-residents

I am travelling from India to Amsterdam with a layover at London, where I have to change airports from Heathrow to Gatwick. Do I require a transit visa?

I have a Dutch residence permit which is valid until next year. Does this exception statement apply to me? *You can transit without a visa if you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland.*

Comment: "Does this exception statement apply to me?": Is your residence permit in the form of an EU-standard card?  (Is there a bull on the front?)

Comment: Yes,It is a EU standard card (with the bull). My concern is more about changing the airport :(

Comment: Since you're changing airports, you need to look at the transit rules that apply to those who need to pass through passport controls.